# Get result metadata using hal3 in android

Tags: android, camera, hal

this problem is about HAL3 of android
I want to know when use capture method in CameraDevice. 
is it real working class which is CameraDevice.CaptureListener?
it was possible to get image data but couldn't receive result metadata.

this is ResultMetaDataListener.

class ResultMetaDataListener extends CameraDevice.CaptureListener{

```
    @Override
    public void onCaptureStarted(CameraDevice camera, CaptureRequest request, long timestamp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onCaptureStarted(camera, request, timestamp);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraDevice camera, CaptureRequest request, CaptureResult result) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCaptureCompleted(camera, request, result);
        Log.i(TAG, "Capture result is available");
        Integer reqCtrlMode;
        Integer resCtrlMode;
        if (request == null || result ==null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "request/result is invalid");
            return;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Capture complete");
```

and this is capture Method. mCamera is CameraDevice object.

ResultMetaDataListener resultListener = new ResultMetaDataListener();
            mCamera.capture(captureBuilder.build(), resultListener, mOpsHandler);

please, help me if you know about that